# SUMPRODUCT inside ARRAYFORMULA in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have a `SUMPRODUCT` equation that works fine on one row:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(O4:O10-O3:O9,E2-P4:P10,N(E2>P4:P10))
```

However, instead of copying it for each `E` row I want to use `ARRAYFORMULA` to automatically generate the values using `E2:E`.

When I try the following:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(O4:O10-O3:O9,E2:E-P4:P10,N(E2:E>P4:P10)))
```

I get the error `Array arguments to MINUS are of different size`.

I know there is another question asking something similar, but there is no explanation of the formula in the answer so I cannot apply it to my situation easily.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by this part

```
E2:E-P4:P10
```

The end part in `E2:E` is an open reference, meaning that it will be take the last row of the sheet.

One possible solution could be to change `E2:E` by `E2:E8` or something similar in order to make this part of the formula have the same number of rows as `P4:P10`